# Make a function similar to modulo that also works with negative numbers

Tags: math, modulo

I need to make a function `f(a,b)` that will give the following results:

```
f(0, 3) = 0
f(1, 3) = 1
f(2, 3) = 2
f(3, 3) = 0
f(4, 3) = 1... (this works exactly like a%b)
```

However it should also follow this pattern for negative numbers:

```
f(-4, 3) = 2
f(-3, 3) = 0
f(-2, 3) = 1
f(-1, 3) = 2
f( 0, 3) = 0
```

I currently found this solution:

```
x = a % b
return a < 0 && mod != 0 ? mod + b : mod;
```

However this feels way too complicated and slow for what I'm trying to achieve. Isn't there a simpler way to generate a sequence similar to modulo that continues for negative values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo operation behavior depends on programming language - see [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages)

For example, in Python `print(-4 % 3)` gives `2`

Seems you are using C-like language, where remainder has the same sign as dividend. In this case you can use such formula ([ideone](https://ideone.com/AJ72PA))

```
(a % b + b) % b
```

Also the only comparison is enough to correct negative value (so avoiding double `%`)

```
rem = a % b;
if (rem < 0) rem += b;
```

Comment: Indeed, I was using Java, didn't know modulo's behavior varied! (a % b + b) % b is exactly the kind of solution I wanted, it's way cleaner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a general solution for any `b`, but if you need just to wrap around an array from both sides and you are decrementing the index by 1 (or by at most `a`) a valid and even shorter solution for any `b >= -a` is:

```
(a + b) % b
```

Comment: In my case a can take pretty much any value so this wouldn't work, but thanks anyways!